# Constructing a metric subspace of $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$, where $X_\alpha$ is a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that for each $\alpha\in I$, $(d_\alpha,X_\alpha)$ is a metric space. (The indexing set $I$ is arbitrary.) I want to find a maximal subset $Y$ of the product space $X=\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$ that is a metric space under the supremum metric $d(x,y)=\sup_{\alpha\in I}d_\alpha(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)$.

This is, as far as I am aware, the only "natural" metric for a product of metric spaces, but it is only a metric if $\sup_{\alpha\in I}d_\alpha(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)<\infty$ for every $x,y\in Y$, and it is not clear how to select such a subset in general. Looking online, I see an example using the space of bounded functions on a normed vector space, but on an arbitrary metric there is no "base point" from which to define the notion of "bounded". What is the standard approach to metrizing such spaces? (I am aware that, e.g. $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ is not metrizable, but there are several "reasonable" subsets of this that are metrizable.)

Comment: There are other metrics.  Consider $$d_\omega(x,y) = \sum_\alpha \frac{d_\alpha(x,y)}{2^\alpha}$$

Comment: @nomen That assumes (1) that $I\subseteq\Bbb R$, since you are attempting to calculate $2^\alpha$, and (2) that $I$ is countable, since you are attempting to sum over $\alpha\in I$. As I stated, $I$ is arbitrary and may be uncountable or even bigger than $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}$I will assume that the spaces $X_\alpha$ are non-trivial. Suppose that $Y\subseteq X$, and fix a point $p\in Y$. For $y\in Y$ let $\supp(y)=\{\alpha\in I:y_\alpha\ne p_\alpha\}$. By a basic open set in $Y$ I mean the intersection with $Y$ of a standard product basic open set in $X$, i.e., one that restricts finitely many coordinates. The intersection of countably many basic open nbhds of $p$ restricts at most countably many coordinates, so $Y$ has no countable base at $p$ unless $\bigcup_{y\in Y}\supp(y)$ is countable. Let $S=\bigcup_{y\in Y}\supp(y)$; then $Y$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of the countable product $X_S=\prod_{\alpha\in S}X_\alpha$. If $I$ is uncountable, there seems to be no non-arbitrary way to choose a countable subset of $I$, so you’re really restricting yourself to countable $I$.

For countable $I$ the product $X$ is always metrizable, but the function that you describe does not generate the product topology even when it’s defined. For example, if $X_n=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete metric for each $n\in\omega$, $X$ as a topological space is a Cantor set, while your function is the discrete metric on $X$.

Comment: I'm confused by your claim that I am restricted to countable $I$. Let $Y=[0,1]^\Bbb R$ and $p(x)=0$; then the supremum metric is a metric (since the diameter of $Y$ is 1), and so $Y$ is metrizable, yet clearly $\bigcup_{y\in Y}{\rm supp}(y)=\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Mario: Since you said that $Y$ was a subspace of the product space $X$, I was assuming that you wanted it to have the topology that it inherits from the product. If you just want to find a subset of $X$ on which $d$ is a metric, that’s a completely different problem.

Comment: I meant subspace in the metric sense, i.e. the metric on $Y$ is the same as the (extended) metric on $X$. I guess these two notions do not coincide here, since as you point out the supremum metric only generates the product topology when $I$ is finite. (When $I$ is countable, I think you can use some trick like $d(x,y)=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}d(x_n,y_n)/n$ to make it still generate the product topology, but that doesn't generalize to uncountable $I$, and of course it can't since the product topology isn't metrizable there.) I think my metric's topology is called the box topology.

Comment: @Mario: When your $d$ is a metric it generates a topology that is coarser than the box topology: the box topology on the product of infinitely many non-trivial spaces is never first countable. (If $I$ is countable you can replace each $d_n$ by an equivalent bounded metric $d_n'$ and then take $\sum_n2^{-n}d_n'(x,y)$.)

Comment: Also, your first comment was indeed the direction I was going for in this question. I am trying to investigate the structure of the set of subsets of $X$ on which $d$ is a metric. The only such subsets I can think of are those of the form $Y=\{x\in X|d(x,p)<\infty\}$ for some fixed $p\in X$. Are these subsets maximal, and are there any other maximal subsets?

Comment: @Mario: If $Y$ is such a subset, fix $p\in Y$ arbitrarily; you must have $d(x,p)<\infty$ for each $x\in Y$, so you can clearly expand $Y$ to $\{x\in X:d(x,p)<\infty\}$.

Comment: Fascinating. Since the relation $d(x,y)<\infty$ is an equivalence relation, these different $Y$ subsets are the equivalence classes in $X$. In the topology generated by $d$ on $X$, each $Y$ is clopen, so they must be the connected components of $X$, if $Y$ itself is connected. Which leads me to the next question: if each $X_\alpha$ is connected, does it follow that $Y$ is connected?

Comment: @Mario: I’ve not had time to think about it properly, but I suspect so. It’s definitely true if each $X_\alpha$ is path-connected.